# Switch based on checkbox tied between two cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

Is possible to get switch based on checkboxes tied between two cells in Google Sheets (preferably without scripts)?
Like Radio buttons, Option button, Quiz option or Multiple choice in Google Forms or MS Word.

It should work like this:
01. When i check A1 checkbox to TRUE checkbox in B1 give FALSE.
02. When i check B1 checkbox to TRUE checkbox in A1 give FALSE.


Actually I want Radio button / Option Button from MS Word.
Like here in time 01:39 - https://youtu.be/LjtrPUDfDeU?t=99
Modifiing the Check Box solution seems to me the easiest, but I may be wrong.
Please correct me if you know of a better solution.


I tried to do it with if():
A1`=if(B1=TRUE;FALSE;)`
B1`=if(A1=TRUE;FALSE;)`
A1 and B1 cell is checkbox from "Data validation".
But this is not work (Rather stupidity).

I created a test sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lL94ZwEo7Arvb9NrDRpNTgHmyfhzIc2KJ3dOoIEP86M/edit?usp=sharing



I didn't have a solution on the Internet.
I don't think that's even possible, as a last resort I came to ask here.

Comment: not possible. you will need a script for that

Comment: So you want to make the checkbox behave like a radio button? This cannot be done without disabling the ability to actually check the box or using google app scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are asking for a radio button behavior which is not currently supported in Google Sheets as of today. It is not possible without a script to "trick" the checkbox to have this behavior without also disabling your ability to hit the checkbox.

The downside to doing a script is there is a delay but it does work... set your checkboxes and give them a named range Data->Named Ranges name them RadioButton1 then the following script will handle them like a radio button (you could easily modify the code to handle other radio button sets):

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var editRange = e.range;
  var rb1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("RadioButton1");

  // return if out of range
  if (editRange.getSheet().getSheetName() != rb1.getSheet().getSheetName()) return;

  var radioRange = { // RadioButton1 range
    top : rb1.getRow(),
    bottom : rb1.getLastRow(),
    left : rb1.getColumn(),
    right : rb1.getLastColumn()
  };

  var thisRow = editRange.getRow();
  if (thisRow < radioRange.top || thisRow > radioRange.bottom) return;

  var thisCol = editRange.getColumn();
  if (thisCol < radioRange.left || thisCol > radioRange.right) return;

  // make RadioButton1 named range behave like radio button
  var numRows = rb1.getNumRows();
  var numCols = rb1.getNumColumns();
  var writeValues = []
  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
    var row = []
    for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {
      var currentRange = rb1.getCell(i,j);
      var radioValue;
      if ( currentRange.getA1Notation() == editRange.getA1Notation() ) {
        radioValue = true;  
      } else {
        radioValue = false; 
      }
      row.push(radioValue)
    }
    writeValues.push(row)
  }
  rb1.setValues(writeValues)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an onEdit trigger which will run the function linked to it with the `e` object as parameter [1]. Then, use the below code which will get the checkboxes in 'C2:D2' range from Sheet1, and will uncheck [2] them all first and check [3] the edited checkbox after (only if it was unchecked previously):

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var selectedCheckbox = e.range; 
  var oldValue = e.oldValue;
  var row = selectedCheckbox.getRow();
  var col = selectedCheckbox.getColumn();
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  //Checkbox range, assuming each pair of checkbox is in the same row. 'C2:D2' in this example.
  var checkboxesFirstColumn = 3;
  var checkboxesRow = 2;
  var numCheckboxs = 2;  
  var checkboxRange = sheet.getRange(checkboxesRow, checkboxesFirstColumn, 1,numCheckboxs);

  if(row == checkboxesRow && col >= checkboxesFirstColumn && col < (checkboxesFirstColumn + numCheckboxs)) {
    //Uncheck all the checkbox in range
    checkboxRange.uncheck();

    //If previous value was false, then check to true
    if(oldValue.toUpperCase() == "FALSE") {
      selectedCheckbox.check();
    }
  }
}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#uncheck

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#check