# Upgrading a script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So i have this script

```
 function onEdit(e) {

  var editRange = e.range;
  var rb1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("RadioButton1");

  // return if out of range
  if (editRange.getSheet().getSheetName() != rb1.getSheet().getSheetName()) return;

  var radioRange = { // RadioButton1 range
    top : rb1.getRow(),
    bottom : rb1.getLastRow(),
    left : rb1.getColumn(),
    right : rb1.getLastColumn()
  };

  var thisRow = editRange.getRow();
  if (thisRow < radioRange.top || thisRow > radioRange.bottom) return;

  var thisCol = editRange.getColumn();
  if (thisCol < radioRange.left || thisCol > radioRange.right) return;

  // make RadioButton1 named range behave like radio button
  var numRows = rb1.getNumRows();
  var numCols = rb1.getNumColumns();
  var writeValues = []
  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
    var row = []
    for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {
      var currentRange = rb1.getCell(i,j);
      var radioValue;
      if ( currentRange.getA1Notation() == editRange.getA1Notation() ) {
        radioValue = true;  
      } else {
        radioValue = false; 
      }
      row.push(radioValue)
    }
    writeValues.push(row)
  }
  rb1.setValues(writeValues)
}
```

from [Switch based on checkbox tied between two cells in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59226666/switch-based-on-checkbox-tied-between-two-cells-in-google-sheets)

so sorry i for got i have put the checkboxes into separate ranges

[What ranges i Have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A3xd.png)

how do i make this now work for multiple ranges please?

also if there is a way to set the cells the check boxes are in rather than using a range to determine the checkbox pairs so i can move them around the sheet and tell the script where to look that would be better

[My Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YWfloYTN1PLjohvIGS0UMGQrR2lnZQCNiIN0_Na1ijM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific.  What do you mean by "multiple ranges"? Edited range? Radio button range?

Comment: thank you so sorry i have updated my request

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

The following example script shows how to toggle checkboxes like radio button in which only one checkbox of two remains checked.  The checkboxes are grouped by rows as shown.

**Code.gs**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let rButton = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("RadioButtons"); // A1:B5

  let rCheck = null;
  if( e.range.getSheet().getName() === rButton.getSheet().getName() ) {
    if( e.range.getRow() < rButton.getRow() || e.range.getRow() > rButton.getLastRow() ) return;
    if( e.range.getColumn() < rButton.getColumn() || e.range.getColumn() > rButton.getLastColumn() ) return;

    // unchecked does not become checked, only check becomes unchecked
    let offset = e.range.getColumn() === 1 ? 1 : -1;
    e.range.offset(0,offset,1,1).uncheck();
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [Range.offset()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offset(Integer,Integer))
- [Range.uncheck()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#uncheck)

Comment: been getting a error  :-6:34:25 PM Notice Execution started
6:34:25 PM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit @ checkboxToggle.gs:13

Comment: You are running from spreadsheet context, not from script editor?

Comment: i added a link to my script so you can look if that's ok :- [link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YWfloYTN1PLjohvIGS0UMGQrR2lnZQCNiIN0_Na1ijM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your named ranges were wrong.  Did you want it by column or by row?

Comment: by row please if you can

Comment: I revised my script to work by row rather than by column